# How to let my web output data to my apps?

Tags: xml, xcode, mobile, web

I am a Mobile developer, and I know nothing about web development.

I have a mobile app which need to receive a string from my web each time it starts, a simple string, just one number, 1 or 0.

I use Yola.com to host my web, so I can not change CSS or Html.

The API I use:
network.request( "http://www.google.ca", "GET", networkListener )

The thing is I can get data from any web, but just can not get data from any Yola.com hosted web, which give me a error in the app.

Is there anything I can do?

Or just introduce me some other host who can let me get data at a good price.
(I don't wanna pay too much as all I need is go get 1 number.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a page on your web host that has only the text content, either 1 or 0. There is no need for css or html in this case.

Answer (score 0):

or you can pass the string as POST message from web to mobile app. you can easily do it using javascript. So, your mobile app (after starting) will make request to web and web will reply back the string ( just like api call). Also, if you want to make a secure call, you should go with https call. if you are sending passwords, use MD5 or AES encryption jus to secure the sensitive data.